# Evaluating Limits with $m$ and $n$ as positive integers

Tags: limits

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers , Evaluate

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(1+x)\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\cdots\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)^m-1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+2x}\cdots\sqrt[n]{1+nx}-1}
\end{equation}

I have been having a lot of trouble with this limit, I know I can use L'hopitals rule. However I was told that I need to use it for a product of $n$ function,( a product rule for $n$), as well as try $n=1,\, n=2,\, n=3,\, n=4$ etc.

Either way I'm lost !! Please help me get through this beastly limit.

Comment: Could you edit the contents of the link in the body of the post? It makes it more accessible for other users.

Comment: Well, the limit of both the numerator and denominator are both $0$ so L'Hopital's rule definitely applies.

Comment: Can you show that the limit of the derivative of the numerator is $1+1+\cdots+1=m$?

Comment: I already edited it for you 9 minutes ago. Perhaps my edit is not showing yet to anyone else.

Comment: That is the correct answer. Did you use the fact that the derivative of multiple products follows the pattern $(u\cdot v\cdot w)^\prime=u^\prime\cdot v\cdot w+u\cdot v^\prime\cdot w+u\cdot v\cdot w^\prime$?

Comment: Overall tip: take logs to convert products into sums. For this specific one: use the fact that $f'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}f(x) = \frac d{dx}(\log f(x)) \cdot f(x)$ to carry out l'Hopital's rule on your given function of the form $\frac{f(x)-1}{g(x)-1}$. (You can also proceed by writing everything in sight in terms of Maclaurin series.)

Comment: If you follow the pattern I outlined above you will find that each term of the sum on the right has a limit of $1$. The result in the denominator will follow the same pattern with each term of the derivative having a limit of $1$ giving a L'Hopital's rule result of $m/n$.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need L'Hopital: Let

$$f(x)= (1+x)\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\cdots\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)^m,g(x) = (1+x)\sqrt{1+2x}\cdots\sqrt[n]{1+nx}.$$

The limit takes the form

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{g(x) - g(0)} = \frac{(f(x) - f(0))/(x-0)}{(g(x) - g(0))/(x-0)}.$$

By definition of the derivative, this limit equals $f'(0)/g'(0).$

Logarithmic differentiation is a nice way to figure out these derivatives; the computation works out nicely.

Comment: $\ln f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} k\ln (1+x/k).$ Thus $(\ln f)'(x) =  \sum_{k=1}^{m} k [1/(1+x/k)] (1/k) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} 1/(1+x/k).$ But by the chain rule, $(\ln f)'(x) = f'(x)/f(x).$ So we have

$$\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} 1/(1+0/k) = m.$$

Because $f(0) = 1,$ we get $f'(0)=m.$ Same idea for $g.$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k-1}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+kx\right)^{1/k}-1}
\end{equation}
is of type $0/0$ so L'Hopital's rule applies.

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k-1\right]}{\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+kx\right)^{1/k}-1\right]}&=
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^mk\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^{k-1}\displaystyle\prod_{p\ne k}\left(1+\frac{x}{p}\right)^p}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)k\left(1+kx\right)^{1/k-1}\displaystyle\prod_{p\ne k}\left(1+px\right)^{1/p}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{m}1}{\sum_{k=1}^n1}\\
&=\dfrac{m}{n}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I was trying to economize on space by using the product notation. For example, for $k=2$ the term in the numerator is $(1+x)\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\right]^\prime\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)^3\cdots\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)^m$. But I separated out in front of the product the term whose derivative was being taken. Ditto for the denominator.

Comment: Yes, some call the general product rule the general Leibniz rule.

Comment: An alternate version stated for a triple product for example (and following from logarithmic differentiation) is $(uvw)^\prime=(uvw)\left(\frac{u^\prime}{u}+\frac{v^\prime}{v}+\frac{w^\prime}{w}\right)$. For this problem, it might be easier to use this version.